# Parsing text files in Ruby when the content isn't well formed

Tags: ruby, parsing, text

I'm trying to read files and create a hashmap of the contents, but I'm having trouble at the parsing step. An example of the text file is

```
put 3
returns 3
between
 3
pargraphs 1
4
 3
#foo 18
****** 2
```

The word becomes the key and the number is the value. Notice that the spacing is fairly erratic. The word isn't always a word (which doesn't get picked up by /\w+/) and the number associated with that word isn't always on the same line. This is why I'm calling it not well-formed. If there were one word and one number on one line, I could just split it, but unfortunately, this isn't the case. I'm trying to create a hashmap like this.

```
{"put"=>3, "#foo"=>18, "returns"=>3, "paragraphs"=>1, "******"=>2, "4"=>3, "between"=>3}
```

Coming from Java, it's fairly easy. Using [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) I could just use scanner.next() for the next key and scanner.nextInt() for the number associated with it. I'm not quite sure how to do this in Ruby when it seems I have to use regular expressions for everything.

Comment: incidentally, I completely don't recommend it for this example (see my answer), but there is a `StringScanner` library available for Ruby. http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/StringScanner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend just using `split`, as in:

```
h = Hash[*s.split]
```

where `s` is your text (eg `s = open('filename').read`. Believe it or not, this will give you precisely what you're after.

EDIT: I realized you wanted the values as integers. You can add that as follows:

```
h.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.to_i}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know about the splat operator (*) to perform something like that. Thanks!